# how to fix error 13 in python on macos Mojave?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, macos

i am not able to execute simple python codes. 
error message:

```
(Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vervit/Desktop/python/new1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas')
```

`pandas`, `matplotlib`, `numpy` already installed. `pip`, `conda`, `python` updated to latest version

code which I already tried 
1) `sudo python your_python_script.py`
2) `sudo chmod a+rw /path/to/folder/that/you/want/to/write/to`
3) `python3 -m venv env`
`source ./env/bin/activate` 
`python -m pip install google-assistant-sdk[samples]` 
4) Install the package to the user folder:
`python -m pip install --user google-assistant-sdk[samples]`

nothing is working

```
import pandas as pd
import Quandl
df = Quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
print(df.head())
```

should be showing stock prices.

Comment: Have you done `pip install pandas`?.... Or probably `pip3 install pandas` for mac.

Comment: yes installed pandas with first code also tried with conda

Comment: Did you install it inside or outside your environment (If you are in an environment then it must be installed in that environment)? The error clearly says its not installed. How did you install them? Did you do `python3 -m pip...` or `python -m pip`? Mac has both python2 and python3 installed so you need to be careful which one you use. Based on `3)` you installed for python3 but in `1)` you call your script using python2.

Comment: installed using python -m pip , but before all this i have also installed libraries in python2 and after that in python3 also due to this problem

Comment: Use python3. Do your installs with `python3` and run your code with `python3`.

Comment: how to change environment to python3 ?

Comment: Your step `3)`...

Comment: tried that still not working